# Android draw TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY window under status bar

Tags: android

I understand that in SDK >= 26, we can`t draw over the status bar but how can I make my view (TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) full screen and go under the status bar?

I know that the draw overview of some apps (Like messenger) is able to draw under the status bar but no matter what I try, my overlay always stops at the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, after 20 hours of searching, it turned out I could use the LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS and put the yPos to a negative number to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: i was searching this solution for a year man , you just made my day , THANKS

Comment: But not able to get click after that.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually caused by Android avoiding cutouts by default and not the status bar *per se*. This can be seen by running code without the offset workaround given in @saik's answer on a phone that doesn't have cutouts.

As of Android 30 you can use `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS` to prevent Android from avoiding the cutout area instead of using the offset workaround.

Comment: big thanks to @Saik for pointing me in the right direction in the first place!!

Comment: But not able to get click after that.